# Reducing training dataset for architecture testing

Tags: dataset, conv-neural-network, hyperparameter

I want to quickly test many CNN architectures on the MNIST dataset, but I don't want to train each on the whole dataset.

Is it possible to reduce the training dataset size and still be able to accurately determine which model is better?

If so, what's minimum size I can reduce it to?

Answer (score 1):

To give one counterexample, there is a recent paper [*To Pretrain or Not to Pretrain*](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.08671) by Wang, Khabsa, and Ma (2020), quoting the authors:

> Our  findings  in  this  paper  indicate  that  increasing the number
> of training examples for ‘standard’ models such as LSTM leads to
> performance gains that are within 1 percent of their massively
> pre-trained counterparts. [...] One  way  to  interpret  our  results
> is  that ‘simple’ models have better regularization effect when
> trained on large amount of data, as also evidenced in the concurrent
> work (Nakkiran and Sutskever, 2020).

So it *might* be the case that different architectures would have different performance depending on the data size you use for training. In this study, with large enough dataset, they were able to find a simpler model, that had performed almost as well as the complicated one.